# Java Flight Recorder не сохраняет записи

Tags: java

Выставлял самые разные настройки для Java Flight Recorder, но после записи все-равно вылетает одна и та же ошибка.

Screenshot:
http://s016.radikal.ru/i334/1609/86/02219bfb4c69.png

Использую следующую команду для запуска:

```
java -jar ^
-server ^
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures ^
-XX:+FlightRecorder ^
-XX:StartFlightRecording=delay=5s,duration=40s,name=myrecording,filename=C:\JFR\1.jfr ^
 tool.jar
```

Здесь 'My Recording' - имя моей записи.

Пробовал запускать от имени администратора, и сохранять файл в путь исключительно из латинских символов, эффекта ноль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам ведь ясно дает понять ексепшен что не может найти файл. И избавьтесь в пути от русских символов

Comment: С самого начала думал, что связано с этими символами, но в пути их не было.. Оказалось, что JFR предварительно сохраняет данные в рабочий профиль (который как раз их содержит), а уж затем пытается перенаправить в нужное место.